# Automatically add header text to a box via object style in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, object-styles

I'm laying out a book that occasionally has sidebars and footnotes formatted in a box. At the top of each of these boxes, I'd like to have a tiny header that reads '*from the archives*'.

I'm looking for a way to automatically include this with the object style for the box, rather than typing or pasting it over 1000 times. Can anyone suggest a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sadly **not** possible to add any kind of content with styles. Neither images, graphics nor text. In that sense InDesign styles are unlike CSS styling. (An exception is *Bullets and Numbering*, which actually does allow you to add some text content in the beginning of a paragraph, but to use that in this case would be *really* hacky and cumbersome.)

You don't have to paste the same line 1000 times though!

I don't know how your workflow is, but perhaps you could do one of the following:

- Instead of drawing a new frame every time or pasting an empty frame, make a frame which already contains the wanted header and paste that every time.
- Insert all the frames, make sure to use a special paragraph style for the text. Later, when all the frames are inserted, you can copy the wanted header to clipboard and use *Find/Change* to insert it to every frame. For example like this:
  [image]

Comment: Thank you, I suspected there wouldn't be a an equivilent of the css 'content' property, but it's good to know I'm not going the long way around unnecessarily.

Comment: You could also put the header in its own little frame and paste that into the main box as an anchored object. That way you won’t have to find/change but can simply paste the box and start typing in it.